# Hexadecimal of a character

Tags: code-golf, math, string

Given a unicode character `C` (or the first character of a string input), output that character's hex representation. Case does not matter. The output ranges from `\u0000` to `\u9999`.

Test cases

```
A => 41  (65_10 === 41_16)
ʣ => 2A3 (675_10 === 2A3_16)
Ω => 3A9 (937_10 === 3A9_16)
7 => 37  (55_10 === 37_16)
(null byte) => 0 (0_10 === 0_16)
```

-50% byte bonus if you output the javascript escape character `\uXXXX` of the character `C`, e.g. `g => \u0067` and `~ => \u007E`

Comment: -1.  I think by the standards of this community this is a valid question and I don't see any grounds to close it.  However it is especially trivial as evidenced by all the very quick and very short answers.  IMO.  YMMV.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma IMO... YMMV... what!?

Comment: In My Opinion.  Your Mileage May Vary.  Knowing the things work around here, this question will end up hitting the HNQ and get lots of votes anyway.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma +3/-6?

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, 3 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=flRp)

```
~Ti
```

Compiles to `var i=prompt("i = ");(i).charCodeAt().toString(16);`

### Bonus, 13 - 50% = 6.5 bytes

[Try it here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IlxcdSUicHF-VGk0MA)!

```
"\\u%"pq~Ti40
"\\u "        prefix
    %         interpolate with
        ~Ti    you know what this is
      pq   40  pad with 4 0's
```

Comment: It's rare to see a -50% bonus score be more than *double* the non-bonus version. :P

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Yes, that's a tidbit embarrassing ^^"

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, <s>5</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
{iGb{A,6,'Af++=}%}
```

`i` converts to integer, `G` pushes 16, `b` is base conversion.

... and CJam has no way to use 0-9A-Z instead of base-converting to numbers? That's not annoying at all.

```
{          }%   map over number-digits
 A,             generate the digits 0-9
   6,'Af+       generate the "digits" A-F
         +      concat
          =     array-index into the newly generated array
```

Thanks to [@MartinBüttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%c3%bcttner) for saving 2  bytes!

Comment: `{iGb{A,6,'Af++=}%}`

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 14 bytes

Interestingly, this is 14 bytes with and without the bonus.

No bonus:

```
c->hex(Int(c))
```

Bonus:

```
c->"\\u"lpad(hex(Int(c)),4,0)
```

Both are lambda functions that accept `Char`s and return strings. To call a lambda, assign it to a variable.

We get the code point associated with the `Char` using `Int()`, then convert to hexadecimal using `hex()`. For the bonus, we left pad to 4 characters with zeros and prepend `\\u`. The backslash needs to be escaped in the string.

Comment: Julia has automatic string concatenation? o-O

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Here it's actually a combination of two features: Julia uses multiplication to concatenate strings, and in some cases the `*` can be omitted for multiplication since Julia has coefficient literals (or whatever you want to call it when `2x` means `2*x`).

Comment: ... I remember why I got Julia. Cool language! :D

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 5.5 bytes

```
"\u%04X"qe%
```

The code is **11 bytes** long and qualifies for the **-50%** bonus. Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%5Cu%2504X%22qe%25&input=%CA%A3).

#### How it works

```
"\u%04X"     e# Push that format string, i.e., a literal "\u", followed by
             e# an integer in hexadecimal, 0-padded to 4 characters.
        q    e# Read all input.
         e%  e# Apply string formatting.
```

The online interpreter will happily treat the input string as the code point of its sole character. This does *not* work in the Java interpreter, so it might be a feature or a bug.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 4 bytes

```
.HCz
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.HCz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=A%0A%CA%A3%0A%CE%A9%0A7&debug=0).

Pyth doesn't do unicode for string conversions, instead uses ISO-8859, so cost one more byte.

```
.H            Hex representation
 C            Unicode code point
  z           Input string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [TeaScript](http://github.com/vihanb/teascript), 5 bytes

```
xcT16
```

I'm very sure I have a unicode shortcut for 16

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22xcT16%22&inputs=%5B%22%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false%7D)

Comment: Isn't m=16 from the docs?

Comment: @BlockCoder1392 yeah but I'd still have to replace `16` with `(m` which isn't any shorter

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>30</s> 54 / 2 = 27 bytes

```
s=>"\\u"+("000"+s.charCodeAt().toString(16)).slice(-4)
```

The bonus helped a bit

[Try it online at ESFiddle](http://vihanserver.tk/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3D%20s%3D%3E%22%5C%5Cu%22%2B(%22000%22%2Bs.charCodeAt().toString(16)).slice(-4)%0Af('%C3%A5')) (all browsers work)

Comment: At least we know that this is the absolute hard minimum. I'm sure the bonus will help out here.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 50 - 50% = 25 bytes

```
"\u"<>IntegerString[First@ToCharacterCode@#,16,4]&
```

Ignore the error. Mathematica does not recognize the escape code `\u`, so just escapes the `\` and gives a `Syntax:stresc` message.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 5 bytes

```
Uc sG
```

Very simple. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VWMgc0c=&input=ImEi)

#### How it works

```
Uc sG  // Implicit: U = input, G = 16
Uc     // Take the char code of U.
   sG  // Turn it into a base-16 string.
       // Implicit: output last expression
```

#### Bonus version, 20 bytes * 0.5 = 10

```
"\\u{'0³+Uc sG)t0-4
```

Not as simple. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=IlxcdXsnMLMrVWMgc0cpdDAtNCA=&input=ImEi)

#### How it works

```
          // Implicit: U = input, G = 16
"\\u{     // Take the string "\u", and add:
 '0³+     //  Take 3 "0"s, plus
 Uc sG)   //  the hex char code of the input.
 t0-4     //  Take the last 4 chars.
          // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 27/2 = 13.5 bytes

```py
lambda x:r'\u%04X'%(ord(x))
```

No online link because apparently ideone's Python 2 version doesn't support Unicode string literals.

Answer (score 1):

## , 3 chars / 8 bytes

```
ï⒞ⓧ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=%CA%A3&code=%C3%AF%E2%92%9E%E2%93%A7)</kbd>

Superbly simple. Convert to charcode, then to hex.